# Firefox doesn't show the CSS ::before pseudo element correctly, why?

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

open this link in firefox and chrome to see the difference 
http://jsfiddle.net/79cEb/8/
there is a small space around the ::before element in firefox
how can I make it fit the parent element? like it's supposed to be...
this is how it looks in firefox:
[image: this is how it looks in fire fox]

and here is from chrome:
[image: the image from chrome]

the HTML code

```
<button class="like" onclick="item_like()">500</button>
```

the CSS code

```
.like{
float: left; 
height: 30px; 
margin: 12.5px 0; 
background-color: #FAFAFA; 
border-radius: 4px; 
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
padding: 0 10px 0 0; 
margin: 12.5px 10px; 
background-color: #000; 
font: 16px/30px arial; 
color: #FFF; 
border:none;
}

.like::before{
float: left; 
width:30px; 
content: 'like'; 
margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
padding: 0 5px;
background-color: #FF7373; 
color: #FFF; 
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;}
```